# Microcontroller Newbe here. LED color pattern controller for arcade machine

Tags: microcontroller, led

I am building an arcade machine and I want to make a cool led light display for the marquee.

You can see pictures of what I'm talking about here.

[image]

[image]

I want to light up each one of those holes with an LED, and make it so I can program the LED's to create different effects.

I have no experience with micro controllers, but I do have some programing experience (PHP, javaScript) and good soldering skills.

I don't have a clue where to start though. I'm looking for some advice and guidance.

Comment: This is too broad for the q & a format we have here. You should try googling `Launchpad LED Strip`, `msp430 led strip` or `Arduino LED Strip` for many projects that do what you want. LED Strip reffering to rgb leds that are individually controlled. Youtube the same things for videos. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Get an Arduino and a strip of individually addressable RGB LED 'pixels' from Adafruit.

Adafruit has a great tutorial on using these LEDs with the Arduino.

Here's a link to the product page: https://www.adafruit.com/products/306#Description